# Delete all rows in a tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I added a button on the uinavigationbar I want to use it to delete all the rows of uitablview

How can I do that?

`[self.tableView reloadData]`

is not working here

Comment: don't forget to delete the data from your dataSource before calling reloadData

Comment: Did you delete all the data in the model too?

Comment: When you don't state how you populate your table, what is the point of asking one how to clear table rows? -1

Comment: the codes i have checked are not working on my project

Comment: got it.Its my simple mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the button action event remove all the objects from itemArray then reload tableView  data. Before this make sure that in tableView delegate numberOfRowInsection you are passing itemArray count like that:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [itemArray count];
}

// button action//

-(IBAction)deleteTableViewData
{
     [itemArray removeAllObjects];
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i checked this code.it not workedi checked this code.it not worked

Comment: can you please show the error or your navigation bar button action

Comment: k.i'll update my question in few minutes

Answer (score 2):

First remove all objects from the datasource:

```
[dataArray removeAllObjects]
```

and then reload the `UITableView`

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

Comment: i checked this code.it not worked

Comment: @PraphinSP How do you manage your datasource?

Comment: there is no mistake in delegate and datasourse

Answer (score 1):

[array removeAllObjects];

Clear the data source and then reload the data

Comment: i checked this code.it not worked

Answer (score 1):

You are using an array to populate the UITableView. Remove all the objects from there and reload your data.

Make sure your numberOfRowsInSection is returning the array count and not a static value. And then do this:

```
[dataSourceArray removeAllObjects];
[tableView reloadData];
```